# Iterating over mongo cursor gives me empty results

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I'm using the MongoDB API on Python and was trying to iterate over the results of a query, I know that the find() method returns me a cursor and that I can iterate through it like a list in python.
the code I was running looks like this:

```
query_results = mongo_collection.find(query)
emails_dict = {x.get("userId"): x.get("emailAddr") for x in query_results}
send_emails_dict = {x.get("userId"): x.get("sendEmailNotification") for x in query_results}
```

But for some strange reason both the dictionaries that I'm trying to create are returned as empty, I checked the results of the query and it's not empty, meaning that there are documents in the query_result. Any clue what's going on? Is this a know bug from pymongo?

Comment: how do you know the query result is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```py
query_results = mongo_collection.find(query)

emails_dict = {}
send_emails_dict = {}

for doc in query_results:
    emails_dict |= {doc["userId"]: doc["emailAddr"]}
    send_emails_dict |= {doc["userId"]: doc["sendEmailNotification"]}
```

Or perhaps more efficiently:

```py
query_results = mongo_collection.find(query)

emails_dict = {}
send_emails_dict = {}

for doc in query_results:
    emails_dict[doc["userId"]] = doc["emailAddr"]
    send_emails_dict[doc["userId"]] = doc["sendEmailNotification"]
```

Comment: I was going to update my answer to this - saved me the effort! Only caveat is you might want to check the fields exist to avoid a key error.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a `.find()` it returns a cursor which can be iterated.

Once you have exhausted the cursor it won't return any further values. A simple fix in your code (assuming there's not a huge number of records) is to create a list from the cursor:

```
query_results = list(mongo_collection.find(query))
```

Then both the queries should work.

Alternatively put the query results in a for loop and create the dicts from the resulting record, rather than using the dict comprehension twice.

Comment: The problem is that the query result could potentially be very large in number of records and converting the results to a list can take a long time, that's why I was using the list comprehension, to essentially avoid an additional computation

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [rewind](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.rewind) the cursor:

```
query_results = mongo_collection.find(query)
emails_dict = {x.get("userId"): x.get("emailAddr") for x in query_results}
query_results.rewind()
send_emails_dict = {x.get("userId"): x.get("sendEmailNotification") for x in query_results}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing for loop and run again AS there is no need to add for loop as the function find returns the specific data with that email address you gave as a parameter

Comment: How is that supposed to solve the issue? I need to make a new dictionary based on the entire result from the query

Comment: @Shubham Patel - Welcome to SO! Try adding more info on why removing the for loop works.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil, I have edited my comment ,is it fine ?

Comment: @ShubhamPatel - I didn't downvote, someone else did. That's an improved answer but I don't think it solves OP's problem, they have to iterate on the results.